# Send a datetime value to Salesforce object through SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, datetime

I have a SSJS script that updates a field on the campaign member object.

I now need to update one more field, which is a datetime field. Thing is, I don't know how to correctly parse the date I have to send to Salesforce. I tried a couple things but it alwyas fails.

Here's the script (I have put a comment "new script line" on what I have added to the functioning script):

```
    <script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");

var debug = 1;
var records = DataExtension.Init("unsubscribesFromQuickLink");
var data = records.Rows.Retrieve({Property:"updatedFlag",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:0});
var datalength = data.length;
var dateToUpdate = new Date().toISOString(); // new script line


for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i ++) {
    var sf_fieldUpdateString = [];
    //sf_fieldUpdateString.push('Id');
    //sf_fieldUpdateString.push(data[i].CampaignMemberId);
    sf_fieldUpdateString.push('HasOptOutOfTalent__c');
    sf_fieldUpdateString.push(data[i].HasOptOutOfTalent__c);
    sf_fieldUpdateString.push('LastUpdateHasOptOutOfTalent__c');  //new script line 
    sf_fieldUpdateString.push(dateToUpdate); // new script line

    var updateSFObject = "";
    updateSFObject += "\%\%[ ";
    updateSFObject += "set @salesforceFields = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('CampaignMember',";
    updateSFObject += "'" + data[i].CampaignMemberId + "','" + sf_fieldUpdateString.join("','") + "'";
    updateSFObject += ") ";
    updateSFObject += "output(concat(@salesforceFields)) ";
    updateSFObject += "]\%\%";


   // var idToUpdate = data[i].SubscriberKey;

    try {

      results = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent(updateSFObject);

     // var processing = records.Rows.Update({flag:'1'}, ['SubscriberKey'], [idToUpdate]);

    } catch (e) {

      if (debug) { Write("<br>updateSF error: " + Stringify(e)); }

    }

}
</script>
```

The script returns an error when I run it, and it's due to the date I am trying to send to SFDC.

I have a process that updates that exact same field in a cloudpage with ampscript, and this is how I set the date there:

```
set @LastUpdateDate = Format(DateParse(now(),1), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000")
```

How do I achieve this in SSJS? How can I correctly send a value to a datetime field of a Salesforce object?

Comment: It has to be ISO format, you can format it using AMPscript, not sure if SSJS has this option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my notes - I don't think you need ms, but you need the offset.

SSJS:

```
/* date formatting */
var time = Platform.Function.Now();
 
var year = time.getFullYear();
var month = (time.getMonth()+1);
var day = time.getDate();
if(month<10) month = '0'+month;
var h = time.getHours();
var m = time.getMinutes();
var s = time.getSeconds();
var ms = time.getMilliseconds();

if(h<10) h = '0'+h;
if(m<10) m = '0'+m;
if(s<10) s = '0'+s;
var sfmcOffsetFromUTC = "-06:00" 

/* datetime */
var formattedTimestamp = year + "-" + month + '-' + day + 'T' + h + ':' + m + ":" + s + sfmcOffsetFromUTC; 

/* date */
var formattedDate = year + "-" + month + '-' + day;
```

AMPScript is easier:

```
FormatDate(Now(),"iso")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have indicated ISO time is required.

Use this ready to go line straight into your code:

`var isoTime = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent("\%\%=FormatDate(Now(),'iso')=\%\%");`

Comment: Thanks, I went for @Jonas code but I guess this gives the expected result as well. Will definitely keep this in my notes and try it out next time.